# How can a maven multi-module project include gradle sub-projects?

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, pom.xml

We have a maven multi-module project, that we want to gradually migrate over to a gradle-project.

For starters, I would like to migrate only a few sub-projects to gradle, but keep them as sub-projects to the parent maven-project build.

Is there a supported/recommended way to this?

Pointers to plugins, or any advice how to best do this appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really sure, that there is a straightforward solution for such a task. But you can take a look at the [gradle-maven-plugin](https://github.com/LendingClub/gradle-maven-plugin) which allows to run Gradle tasks in Maven. From the plugin description:

> To use the plugin, simply declare the plugin and bind it to the maven
>   lifecycle phase of your choice:
>
> ```
> <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.fortasoft</groupId>
>     <artifactId>gradle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
>     <version>1.0.8</version>
>     <configuration>
>         <tasks>
>             <!-- this would effectively call "gradle doSomething" -->
>             <task>doSomething</task>
>         </tasks>
>     </configuration>
>     <executions>
>         <execution>
>             <!-- You can bind this to any phase you like -->
>             <phase>compile</phase>
>             <goals>
>                 <!-- goal must be "invoke" -->
>                 <goal>invoke</goal>
>             </goals>
>         </execution>
>     </executions>
> </plugin>
> ```
>
> Now when you run maven, gradle will be invoked and execute the
>   "doSomething" task defined in build.gradle.
>
> Obviously you can change the task(s) to suit your needs.
>
> In this example, the gradle invocation will happen during the maven
>   "compile" phase, but this can be easily changed by changing the
>    element value.

Unfortunately can't say, how to share the Gradle module artifacts without posting it to some local repository.

Answer (score 3):

In order to install the built artifact to your local maven repo, just add the [maven plugin for gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) to your `build.gradle` file. Then, use the `install` task instead of `doSomething` in @Stanislav's pom.xml example.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the gradle project that you're trying to build,

```
uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
```

Then call `gradle build publishToMavenLocal` this will build the project/module and push it to the local maven repo (.m2) as well as a generated pom file. Then you can use it as your previous normal maven module with the pom file.

Read from https://proandroiddev.com/tip-work-with-third-party-projects-locally-with-gradle-961d6c9efb02 to know more.